# How to remove curly braces from text file?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove curly braces from text file. This is my code

This is my text file

```
(        .    ||         .              )   


      .      =               


                         (){



              =        .              ?         .              ("              ") :         .   .                  
                    .     .    =        (           )+8+"  "        
     (                     &&    _      ("               ")!="")    

                ()
```

it is not working

```
import re
symbols =re.compile(r'{{.*?}}',flags=re.UNICODE)
result = symbols.sub(" ",result)
```

Any suggestions?

I got solution, without using re

```
text.replace('{', '')
text.replace('}', '')
```

Comment: What is this crazy post? Do you want to remove only curly brackets or do you want to remove all that is inside curly brackets? If curly brackets are not closed (i.e. there is only an opening bracket but not a closing bracket) do you want to remove all the content after the opening curly bracket until the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
text.replace('{', '')
text.replace('}', '')
```

should work fine, I like

```
text = 'abc{def}ghi'
text.translate(None, '{}')
```

or

```
unitext = u'abc{def}ghi'
unitext.translate({ord('{'):None, ord('}'):None})
```

It's probably even faster, if you do a lot of replacing.

Answer (score 3):

Your pattern, `{{.*?}}`, will change a string like `foo{{bar}}baz` to `foo baz`. But since nothing like `{{bar}}` appears in your file, I don't think that's really what you want to do.

If you want to remove `{` and `}` characters, try this:

```
symbols = re.compile(r'[{}]',flags=re.UNICODE)
```

Also note that `symbols.sub(" ",result)` will replace them with spaces. If you want to just remove them, use `symbols.sub("",result)`.

And of course, for something this simple, regular expressions are probably overkill. Basic string manipulation functions will probably suffice.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('output_file', 'w') as f_out:
    with open('input_file') as f_in:
        for line in f_in:
            for ch in ['{', '}']:
                line = line.replace(ch, '')
            f_out.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

***[RE](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)*** it is very slow, i suggest to use simple [replace](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm):

```
text.replace('{', '')
text.replace('}', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following would remove all curlys from mystring.

```
import re

mystring = 'my stuff with {curly} braces'
result = re.sub(r'[{}]', '', mystring)
```